# MFC C++ put a 1000 MS sleep on main thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, sleep, thread-sleep

Simple enough question I am sure.

Using MFC C++, what header do I need to include and what functions do I need to call to place a 1000 ms sleep on the main thread.

In C# it is easy as Thread.Sleep(1000); so is there something as simple as that in C++?

I am playing a sound and it quits after playing sound. The sound does not get a chance to play for a quits to fast.

Comment: How about just simple Sleep(1)? I believe you don't need to include any header for that.

Comment: `Sleep` is not a good solution for this unless it really doesn't matter if the main thread is not in sync with the sound. The sound-playing thread should signal an event that tells the main thread it's OK to exit. `CreateEvent`, `SetEvent`, `WaitForSingleObject`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
#include <cstdlib>

std::sleep(1);
```

Arternatively, under C++11:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. It won't let me accept this as an answer yet but I will!

Comment: std::sleep would not compile for me in VS 2015 with MFC, even with the #include <cstdlib>. But the std::this_thread::sleep_for alternative worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick with MFC:

```
#include <windows.h>
```

And then:

```
Sleep(1000);
```

Documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686342(v=vs.85).aspx